# UIPickerView's components width cause alignment problems when customized

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipickerview

My UIPickerView has the same widths as its superview. I'd like to be able to change the components/columns width:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if component == 0 {

        return pickerViewHolder.bounds.width / 100 * 10

    } else if component == 1 {

        return pickerViewHolder.bounds.width / 100 * 45

    } else {

        return pickerViewHolder.bounds.width / 100 * 45
    }

}
```

With that piece of code the width are shown as desired. But there is a variance in the alignment within the component's row. Within the `viewForRow` I set the `NSTextAlignment.Left` what actually works with standard component width or - and there I put the big question mark - with just some custom values like (15, 30, 30) or (30, 30, 30). But if I put the numbers from above or also other combinations less than 100% in total (if that mattered) like (10, 40, 40) or (10, 45, 40) I still get the correct alignment within the selected row but the ones above and below are aligned differently:

[image] [image]

I tried to call methods like `pickerView.setNeedsLayout()` or `pickerView.reloadAllComponents()` in the `viewWillAppear()` but it didn't make a difference.